# filling web form using a windows application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a site which get information of user in one of its pages.
every user has a card which contain his information. I want to write a windows application in Visual C# which read the card and fill web form using those data.
for this reason I have to run a browser in my windows application and run some javascript code to fill that elements in that browser.

does any one how can I run a browser and give to that specific javascript (in url after on page has been loaded) to fill the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a WebBrowser control that you can use in your windows app. As for populating the information on a web page, I would just pass the userID in QueryString to the URL of the page you create (in your WebBrowser control), and in the page add code to retrieve the user information and display it.

Here is some info on the WebBrowser control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you would be better off handing over the data you want to see in the web forms via http post or get. Then let the serverside write the values into the propper forms.